# UISearchbar results filtering

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar where the user can type the text. Basically it is a dynamic company name search. (loaded from ext API) e.g. if the user has typed "MIC", it will show AMIC, BMIC, CMIC, ...MICROSOFT.

I am using the code below

```
NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

My question is;
 1. Is this the best approach for filtering? i.e. For comp name should I use Name starts with OR Name contains, which is the current approach.
 2. The search is not working for spaces. e.g. it returns no results for "COMP NAME"

I'll add comments for additional info as I get answers.
Please suggest.

Comment: All your code does is return an NSRange. How are you actually performing the search?

Comment: I am using a ext API which returns me the results. I store those in an array and also make a copy of the array with the filtered results.

Comment: So what does the code you have shown have to do with the way your external API returns the results?

Comment: It is used for filtering from what the API returns.

Comment: Back to my first question - you have a string, you run a search, and get a range. What do you do with the range?

Comment: I have given most of the info. Could I get some other opinions also.

Comment: Hey, it's not my fault if I can't understand your question!

Comment: I agree with Abizern - saying that you'll provide additional info as answers come in isn't really good practice. You should try to provide enough info so that we can answer your question without having to guess at a bunch of things or with a prolonged back-and-forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only one line of code to go on, it's hard to tell whether or not your search implementation is the "best approach" - providing additional info would be helpful. For example, we don't even know where the `sTemp` variable is coming from or what it contains.

That said:

1. If your results are indeed coming from an external API, it might provide you a speedup to send the search string to that API and have it do the search closer to the data source - having you cache and do a string scan on your entire result set will show some performance slowdowns as your data set size increases. If you're set on doing the search locally, though, then yes, a case-insensitive search is probably your best option.
2. Do you expect results for "COMP NAME"? I'm going to wildly assume that you have some company called "COMPANY NAME", and want your abbreviated "COMP NAME" search to hit on "COMPANY NAME". Then your problem here is that you're doing a compare on the entire string, not parts of it - "COMPANY NAME" doesn't contain the substring "COMP NAME", even in case-insensitive comparison. What you need to do instead is split your search string on whitespace, then check for each company if the name contains *all* the substrings of your query. In this example, then, "COMPANY NAME" contains both the substrings "COMP" and "NAME", so it would match.

Comment: I do not want any abbreviation. I just want that if someone types "ABC XYZ" it should be able to find that..,.currently if there are any spaces in company name, it does not find that result
e.g. for "STATE BANK"